# How to send(post) data from android to website or server

Tags: java, android, json, http, post

I want to pass data from our android apps to website by post method in http response.

What i want now is--i give one add button,if i click the add it opens an edit activity which has edit text and save button,typed some data or text and click the save button it has to go to the website,i dont need of db anymore also.to send or post data in website from our apps.

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener
{
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ProjectsDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);  
         mDbHelper = new ProjectsDbAdapter(this);
            mDbHelper.open();
            //fillData();
            //registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        initView();
    }



    private void initView()
    {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://floating-wildwood-1154.herokuapp.com/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);

        mDbHelper.open();   
        Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
        //startManagingCursor(projectsCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        /* Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter projects = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_row, projectsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(projects);
        */
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
        //as well as the layout information
         dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
          this, R.layout.activity_row, 
          projectsCursor, 
          from, 
          to,
          0);
         setListAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
            mi.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); 
        return true;

    }

     @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

                createProject();

            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
     }

     private void createProject() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ProjectEditActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);   
        }

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            initView();
        }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

projecteditactivity.java

```
public class ProjectEditActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText mTitleText;
     private Button mConfirmButton;
     private Long mRowId;
     private ProjectsDbAdapter mDbHelper;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         mDbHelper = new ProjectsDbAdapter(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_edit);

         mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
         mConfirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

        mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                            : null;
        registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();
    }
    private void setRowIdFromIntent() {
        if (mRowId == null || mRowId.longValue() == 0) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                    : null;

        }
    }

     @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mDbHelper.close(); 
        }
     @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mDbHelper.open(); 
            setRowIdFromIntent();
            populateFields();
        }

     private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {
         mConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    saveState(); 
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    Toast.makeText(ProjectEditActivity.this, getString(R.string.task_saved_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish(); 
                }

            });
     }
     private void populateFields()  {
         if (mRowId != null) {
                Cursor Project = mDbHelper.fetchProject(mRowId);
                startManagingCursor(Project);
                mTitleText.setText(Project.getString(
                        Project.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
                Project.close();
         }
                else {
                    // This is a new task - add defaults from preferences if set. 
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
                    String defaultTitleKey = getString(R.string.pref_task_title_key);
                    String defaultTitle = prefs.getString(defaultTitleKey, null);
                    if(defaultTitle != null)
                    mTitleText.setText(defaultTitle); 
                }

     }

         @Override
            protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
                outState.putLong(ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
            }

         private void saveState() {
            String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
            //if (mRowId == null) 
            if (mRowId == null || mRowId.longValue() == 0)
            {

                long id = mDbHelper.createProject(title);
                if (id > 0) {
                    mRowId = id;
                      }
                   } else {
                            mDbHelper.updateProject(mRowId, title);
                      }


                     }

     }
```

Here i am using db,but i dont want to use db in my apps,what ever i am typing in edit text and after clicking the save button,it has to pass or send the data to server,how can i do that one in my app.

Comment: try to search for how to send data on server in google. This will give you lots of link to do so.

Comment: can you got my requirement@ChintanRathod, how to do that one dude in my code,wtihout using db

Answer (score 1):

To send datas to a website, you can try to call this function on click listener:

```
    protected void sendDatas() {
    mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("YourURL");


            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);//Modify this number with the number of parameter you want to send
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PostParamName", "PostParamValue"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                // JSON parse
                String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                Log.i("httpResponse", response);
                                    //do something with response if needed

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e("httpclient", "Error ClientProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("httpclient", "Error IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mRegisterTask = null;
        }

    };
    mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);

}
```

Declare the mRegisterTask like `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;`
Hope this help.

Comment: I am new to one,in my code,how can i do can you edit  my code and tell, i dont want to use db part,just after clicking the sava button it has to send@Damien

Answer (score 1):

Here is a send post to server method:

```
   public String sendPostRequest(String url) {
        String result = null;
        URI wrapperUrl;
        try {
            wrapperUrl = new URI(url);
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 20000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            int timeoutSocket = 20000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(wrapperUrl);
            post.setParams(httpParameters);
            HttpResponse response = getDefaultClient().execute(post);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            responseEntity.consumeContent();
            result = new JSONObject(jsonResultString);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Reminder, use it in a work thread:

```
 private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {
         mConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    saveState();
                    sendQuestToServer();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    Toast.makeText(ProjectEditActivity.this, getString(R.string.task_saved_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish(); 
                }

            });
     }

private void sendQuestToServer() {
    new Thread(new Runnale() {
         @Override void run() {
            String url = yourServerUrl + youreditText.getText.toString();
            sendQuestToServer(url);
         }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: can you edit my code and tell dude,after clicking the save button it has to go to the server part

Comment: Notice the onClick(), I had added the code based on your code.

Comment: Dude,actually i dont want to use db in my code,can you edit my code and make changes,in projectedit activity only having edittext and save button function,pls remove my db and make changes in my code and tell me,i am not getting in your coding,confusing for me,pls do changes in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the HttpClient  or  HttpPost; 
like this
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serverURL);
        HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(post);
        int sCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (sCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            return response.getEntity();
        } else
            throw new Exception("StatusCode is " + sCode);
```

Comment: How can  i do in my code,without using db,after clicking the save button it has to send to server